# inRange and Mat error

Tags: c++, opencv

I am using OpenCVwith Eclipse.

I need to detect the human skin, so I convert the image to HSV and the I use inRange function to obtain a Mat with the image with the skin in white.

The problem is that now,I need to detect in which components are the white color to modify this pixels in the original frame ( i am changing the skin color with the video camera), but I cant access to the Mat returned in InRange

```
cvtColor(frame,frame,CV_BGR2HSV);
        Mat n;
        inRange(frame, Scalar(0, 10, 60), Scalar(20, 150, 255), n);


        for(int i=0;i<frame.rows;i++)
        {
            for(int j=0;j<frame.cols;j++)
            {

                n.at(&i);
                            //n(i,j);

            }
        }
```

That is the problematic code. When I get to the internal loop, the build fails giving a lot of error refering to the template.

Anyone knows how can I access to this matrix? Is there another way to achieve my objective? Maybe I am complicating the problem.

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

nothing to do with inRange or such, it's just your Mat access code, that is broken.

```
Vec3b & hsvPixel = n.at<Vec3b>(i,j);
// hsvPixel[0] = h;    
// hsvPixel[1] = s;
// hsvPixel[2] = v;
```